# Datagridview with Multiple Datasource - Column Issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with different datasources which is having different columns. For example DataTable1 has A,B and C Column. and DataSource2 has X,Y,Z Columns.

In my windows form application I am allowing user to browse a certain Excel file with Format1 (A,B,C) and Format2 (X,Y,Z). when I load first datasource1 in grid view it shows columns A,B,C and it's data from excel. But when I load Format2. Datagridview retains the format from Datasource1 and shows (A,B,C,X,Y,Z) columns.

Please note that I have common datagridview for both data source. 
Also, I have tried following

```
DataTable.Clear();
DataTable.Columns.Remove("");
AutoGeneratedColumns=False;
```

How do I make sure that datagridview shows only the current Datasource related columns while user is selecting the excel.

DataSource1 - Format 1 - A,B,C
DataSource2 - Format 2 - X,Y,Z

Comment: why are you set `AutoGeneratedColumns=False` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Datagridview.Columns.Clear();
Datagridview.Rows.Clear();
Datagridview.Refresh();
Datagridview.DataSource = null;
```

Comment: This is unlikely to help. The problem is that extra columns are showing that are not wanted. So clearing the rows will do nothing. Additionally this is a data bound girdview so changes to what it should should be made to the datatable it is showing, not to the grid itself

Comment: I don't think so,  the problem is: Datagridview retains the format from Datasource1 and shows (A,B,C,X,Y,Z) columns.

Comment: None of these statements are in any way useful to the person asking the question. When you change the DataSource property of a DataGridView it will erase all its columns and rows and build new ones from the new DataSource. Try ARF's code if you don't believe; he doesn't clear anything on the DGV he just swaps the DataSource

Answer (score 2):

this is working for me:

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("A");
dt1.Columns.Add("B");
dt1.Columns.Add("C");

dt2.Columns.Add("X");
dt2.Columns.Add("Y");
dt2.Columns.Add("Z");

dt1.Rows.Add("a", "a", "a");
dt2.Rows.Add("b", "b", "b");

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;  // set datasource from dt1
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt2; // set datasource from dt2
}
```

Comment: I agree; in a situation where a single datagridview is required to show different sets of data the data should be separated into different datatables and they be swapped in and out. I would also consider having a tab page control and two different grids to allow for easy development and give the user a way to flick back and forth and more easily see which was which but that's effectively she same solution as you have here just with different controls/slightly different UI

Comment: you can use from `new DataTable()` in each action.
like another my answer.